# Expected area of circular region in probability and statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

I have done the $\mathrm{E}\left(x^{2}\right)$ integral several times, even on an online calculator, and still am getting a negative value. But in order to find the area, it obviously needs to be positive. Am I using the wrong formula for this ?.

This is what I did: $\mathrm{E}\left(x^{2}\pi\right)$. I then compute the integral normally, plugging in the below values, and get a negative number. Any help or a different formula would be very helpful !.

[image]

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Recheck your integration AND post what you tried. $\int_{6}^{8}{3 \over 4}\left[1 - \left(7 - r\right)^{2}\right]\left(\pi r^{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}r = {246 \over 5}\,\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral should be

$$\displaystyle \int (\pi r^2) \tfrac34 \left[1-(7-r)^2\right] \, dr = \tfrac{3\pi}{4}\int   \left(-r^4+14r^3-48r^2\right) \, dr = \tfrac{3\pi}{4}   \left(-\frac{{{r}^{5}}}{5}+\frac{7 {{r}^{4}}}{2}-16 {{r}^{3}}\right)+C$$

and so the definite integral should be

$$\displaystyle \int_{r=6}^8 (\pi r^2) \tfrac34 \left[1-(7-r)^2\right] \, dr = \dfrac{-1536\pi}5 - \dfrac{-1782\pi}5= \dfrac{246\pi}5$$ which is positive.  You do not need to worry if the indefinite integral gives negative values, as there is a constant to add